# If Condition not Working ASp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, int

i am trying to check condition before entering into it but it is entering in wrong condition

my conditions are ,

```
 if (Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_CX"].ToString() == "0" && Convert.ToInt64(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_C"]) >= 100000)

if (Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_CX"].ToString() != "0" && Convert.ToInt64(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_C"]) > 10000000)
```

the values are,

```
T_B_CX = 0 and T_B_C = 2500000000
```

it must enter the fist condition i mentioned but it is entering in second condition???

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code between the two conditions?

Comment: thanks to all i check it thoroughly i am getting "0 " this value thats why it is not recognizing value Trim() help me out 1

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to int and do the comparison as below

```
if (Convert.ToInt(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_CX"].ToString()) == 0 && Convert.ToInt64(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_C"]) >= 100000)
```

may be when we get ToString of cell value it returns not exactly string equal to `"0"`, debug and see which value you get for `Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_CX"].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no code between the two conditions, so the first one is taken as expected, then the second one is evaluated till the != 0.

Try to write something like this

```
// Convert everything just one time here 
int tbcx = Convert.ToInt32(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_CX"]);
long tbc = Convert.ToInt64(Target.Tables[0].Rows[0]["T_B_C"]);

if(tbcx == 0 && tbc >= 100000)
    // code here 
else if(tbcx != 0 && tbc > 2500000000)
    // code here
```

Also try to avoid the conversion of an integer value to a string and then check against a string.
It makes no sense. If an integer is stored in that table then convert it to an integer and check against an integer.